# python script throwing an error that i can deal with

Tags: python

I have created the above script to remove unwanted genes from a database. It does work quite well if you only use it once but I re-run it, it giving me an error message such as:
**shutil.Error: Destination path 'path/rejected_database_genes/gene_A.fa' already exists** 
And obviously it stops. I think that the problem arises when there are two or more genes in the file that needs to be removed.
Kind regards, and thanks for your help.

```
import glob, sys, os, shutil
from Bio import SeqIO, SearchIO
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
import argparse

def help_function():
    print 'Hi'
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-input_file', '-i',type=str,help='path_to_data')
opts = parser.parse_args()  

def check_file_exists(filepath, file_description):
    if not os.path.exists(filepath):
        print("The " + file_description + " (" + filepath + ") does not exist")
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        print file_description + " detected"

def remove_empty_files(alleles_files,destination):
    input_handle=open(alleles_files, 'r')
    gene_records=list(SeqIO.parse(input_handle, 'fasta'))

    for gene_record in gene_records:
        #filename=gene_record.id[0]
        #count=0
        if len(gene_record.seq)<5 or 'N'in gene_record.seq:
            print gene_record.id
        elif '-' in gene_record.seq:
            print gene_record.id
            #count+=1
            shutil.move(alleles_files, destination)

def main():
    destination=opts.input_file + '/rejected_database_genes'
    if os.path.exists(destination):
        print 'Folder already exits'
    else:
        os.makedirs(destination)
        print 'Folder has been created'
    files=glob.glob(opts.input_file+'/*.fa')
    #print files
    #sys.exit()     
    for f in files:
        #print f
        #sys.exit()
        alleles_files=glob.glob(f)[0]
        #print alleles_files
        #sys.exit()         
        remove_empty_files(alleles_files,destination)
    print 'Files have been removed'
main()
```

Comment: Can you run the script, rename the results file by hand, and only then rerun it?

Comment: @ArneRecknagel. That will not a very good bioinformatics job. Besides, the problem arises when two or more genes from the same file need to be removed.

Comment: Are you sure you want to *remove* the file? In the code you are clearly trying to *move* it to other destination. If you want to move it the `shutil.move` will try to remove it from existing place and put to destination, but if file already exists in the destination it may fail (for your own security). Easiest way is to check if the file exists in destination and remove it (e.g. `os.remove`). Or maybe you should just remove it in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I wanted was that the moment the script found to remove that file, and storage somewhere else so I can check it later. The problem I was having was that if in the same file there were two unwanted seq, it would through me and error telling me that the file already existed on destination, and stopped. So I managed to solve this problem by added an if statement. The corrected script is the one below:

```
import glob, sys, os, shutil
from Bio import SeqIO, SearchIO
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
import argparse

def help_function():
    print 'Hi'
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-input_file', '-i',type=str,help='path_to_data')
opts = parser.parse_args()  

def check_file_exists(filepath, file_description):
    if not os.path.exists(filepath):
        print("The " + file_description + " (" + filepath + ") does not exist")
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        print file_description + " detected"

def remove_empty_files(alleles_files,destination):
    input_handle=open(alleles_files, 'r')
    gene_records=list(SeqIO.parse(input_handle, 'fasta'))
    geneID_list=[]
    for gene_record in gene_records:
        filename=gene_record.id.split('_')
        geneID=filename[0]+'_'+filename[1]  
        if len(gene_record.seq)<5 or 'N'in gene_record.seq:
            geneID_list.append(geneID)
            shutil.move(alleles_files, destination)
            print geneID_list
        #break              
        if '-' in gene_record.seq:
            geneID_list.append(geneID)
            shutil.move(alleles_files, destination)
            print geneID_list
        #break  
        if len(geneID_list) >0:
            break                   

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) <=1:
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit()
    else:
        check_file_exists(opts.input_file, 'input_file')

    destination=opts.input_file + '/rejected_database_genes'
    if os.path.exists(destination):
        print 'Folder already exits'
    else:
        os.makedirs(destination)
        print 'Folder has been created'
    files=glob.glob(opts.input_file+'/*.fa')
    #print files
    #sys.exit()     
    for f in files:
        #print f
        #sys.exit()
        alleles_files=glob.glob(f)[0]
        #print alleles_files
        #sys.exit()

        remove_empty_files(alleles_files,destination)
    print 'Files have been removed'
main()
```

By adding the third "if" statement, the file is removed as soon as it finds an unwanted sequence, remove the file to destination, and move to check the next file.

Answer (score 0):

the problem you have is in the `shutil.move` line - if you will specify full path to source and destination this will overwrite the existing file and you will not get this error, if you don't want to overwrite and need both of the files, just rename the destination file to something else.

Comment: I just would like to the file moved as soon as it finds the first gene.seq that needs to be removed, and then pass to the next file.

Comment: so use `os.remove` instead of  `shutil.move`